# differences between std::for_each and std::copy, std::ostream_iterator<T> when printing a vector

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, copy, ostream

Recently, I have come across code that prints a `vector` like so

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " ");
```

comparing that to what I am used to (`for_each` or range based for loop)

```
auto print = [](const auto & element){std::cout << element << " ";};
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), print);
```

1. Does the `copy` method create an additional copy? In `for_each` I can have a const reference.
2. The documentation for `copy` states it copies elements from one range to another range. How is `std::ostream_iterator<T>` a range? And if it is then where does it begin and end?
3. I need to templatize the `copy` method, while `for_each` I can just `auto` which seems more convenient.

This makes me feel like the `for_each` method is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, the `ostream_iterator` uses the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&);` overload and will not create additional copies as can be seen in [this demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3vsjPqGjT).
2. The `ostream_iterator` is a single-pass *LegacyOutputIterator* that writes successive objects of type `T`. The destination range can be seen as the `T`s printed on `std::cout`.

> This makes me feel like the `for_each` method is better?

`std::for_each` is a more generic algorithm. With `std::copy` you specify that you aim to copy from one range to another. Some would say that's easier to understand and therefore makes the code easier to maintain.

On the other hand, a plain range-based for loop is pretty easy to understand too:

```
for(auto& element : vec) std::cout << element << ' ';
```